# All windows disappear for a brief moment when performing some actions

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, fullscreen

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after being on Windows for a couple of years. A lot of things have improved, and I feel like this could be my primary OS for years to come. BUT I'm facing some small issues.

When I open a video in full screen in chrome, or move a tab out of the browser suddenly all windows disappear for a brief moment. All I can see is the wallpaper until i release the mouse again. Sometimes it flickers for a bit longer before it starts working normally again. It's not a total deal breaker, but quite annoying.

I have tried to disable hardware acceleration without success.

Anyone know how I can troubleshoot this?